# fuzzy Popup in leaflet Maps

Tags: leaflet

I am creating a map with leaflet, but the text of the popup appear fuzzied. ( Windows 7 Enterprise / Leaflet 0.7.7 / Google Chrome Version 51.0.2704.79 m)

```
<script>

    var mymap = L.map('mapid', {
        center: [42.9050205, 1.8760075],
        zoom: 9
    });

    L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFsfdNDBjZWd2M2x6bDk3c2ZtOTkifQ._QA7i5Mpkd_m30IGElHziw', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution:
            'museodelprado © <a href="http://www.museodelprado.es">www.museodelprado.es</a>',
        id: 'mapbox.streets'
    }).addTo(mymap);

    var MuseosIcon = L.Icon.extend({
        options: {
            shadowUrl: L.Icon.Default.imagePath + '/marker-shadow.png',
            iconSize:     [38, 95],
            shadowSize:   [50, 64],
            iconAnchor:   [22, 94],
            shadowAnchor: [4, 62],
            popupAnchor:  [-3, -76]
        }
    });

     var greenIcon          = new MuseosIcon({iconUrl: L.Icon.Default.imagePath + '/marker-icon-2x-green.png'}),
         redIcon            = new MuseosIcon({iconUrl: L.Icon.Default.imagePath + '/marker-icon-2x-red.png'}),
         blueIcon           = new MuseosIcon({iconUrl: L.Icon.Default.imagePath + '/marker-icon-2x-blue.png'}),
         yellowIcon         = new MuseosIcon({iconUrl: L.Icon.Default.imagePath + '/marker-icon-2x-yellow.png'}); 

            L.marker([42.13675,1.93143],{icon: blueIcon,title: 'MAQ. 1'}).addTo(mymap)
            .bindPopup( "The Museo del Prado is the main Spanish national art museum, located in central Madrid. <br> It features one of the world's finest collections of European art, <br> dating from the 12th century to the early 19th century, <br> based on the former Spanish Royal Collection").openPopup();


        var popup = L.popup();
    </script>
```

[image]

Comment: What version of leaflet and what browser are you using? [Maybe you're hitting this bug](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/3297)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

my browser zoom was not at 100% (press Ctrl+zero)